# what are some careers in psychology where you dont have to interact with people

Tags: psychology, introversion

I am a psychology student, just finished my BA. I like the subject psychology, but i just don't like interacting with people. I would prefer to work alone. I wouldn't mind once in a while interactions such as once a month but being around people everyday is too draining.

Comment: What interests you? See if you can combine your passion in a manner that incorporates your psychology training.